# Reorganize agents and pallets

Tags: netlogo

I have servers, pallets and tags breeds. Each server has a number of assigned pallets `pallets-being-served` and each pallet has an agentset of `tags` (`tags-in-pallet` ). All the tags assigned to a server are in the `my-tags` variable.

I have the following:

```
breed [ servers server ]
breed [ tags tag ]
breed [ pallets pallet ]

pallets-own [
  tags-in-pallet
]

servers-own [
  pallets-being-served
  my-tags
]


to reorganization
  let num-changes-in-reorg (random (num-pallets-by-side ^ 2 - 1) + 1) ; the num of changes
  repeat num-changes-in-reorg [
    let p1 nobody let p2 nobody let t1 nobody let t2 nobody
    let my-pallets n-of 2 pallets  ]
    ask one-of my-pallets [
      set p1 self 
      set p2 other my-pallets
      set t1 [tags-in-pallet] of p1
      set t2 [tags-in-pallet] of p2
    ]
    ask p1 [ set tags-in-pallet t2 ]
    ask p2 [ set tags-in-pallet t1 ]
    ask servers [
      set my-tags (turtle-set [ tags-in-pallet ] of pallets-being-served)
    ]
  ] ; repeat
end
```

The intention is to make some `tags-in-pallet` swaps between pairs of pallets and assign the changed tags to the corresponding server.
The above code seems to work, but It seems inelegant using auxiliary variables p1, p2, t1, t2. Besides, the `ask servers` clause involves all the servers when it is just necessary to refer to the servers where `my-tags` has changed.

Is there a better way to make the swap of tags and reassign them to there corresponding servers?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any restrictions on tags? I am not entirely clear what you are doing, but it seems to me that the easiest way to do what I think you want to do is simply choose `n-of` from each pallet, remove these from the pallets you took them from and add them to the other pallet. If this is a correct interpretation, you want something like (note, not tested and will definitely be wrong):

```
to reorganization
  let num-changes-in-reorg (random (num-pallets-by-side ^ 2 - 1) + 1) ; the num of changes
  let p1 one-of pallets
  let p2 one-of pallets with [not member? self p1]
  let p1-to-p2 n-of num-changes-in-reorg [tags] of p1
  let p2-to-p1 n-of num-changes-in-reorg [tags] of p2
  ask p1 [set tags (turtle-set tags with [not member? self p1-to-p2] p2-to-p1]
  ask p2 [set tags (turtle-set tags with [not member? self p2-to-p1] p1-to-p2]
end
```

I haven't answered the server bit as I am not clear how the servers and pallets connect.

Comment: Thank you. Your approach is to take some of the tags from one pallet to another. I must say that the code is beautiful. My system has servers and each of them has e.g. 9 pallets assigned. My code tries to inter-exchange (to shuffle :-) pairs of pallets in the warehouse (I repeat this `num-changes-in-reorg` times). The trick is that I do not change the pallets I just swap their content (all the tags in the pallet). The reason is that each pallet has a location in the warehouse and if I only move the content of the pallet I can neglect the location of pallets.

Comment: in the process of swapping the pallet contents, I have to update the server's `my-tags` variable with all the tags assigned to the server involved in the change.

Comment: I should only update the `my-tags`variable of the concerned servers in the swap of tags.

Comment: I am still unclear what you are trying to do. Why can't you simply swap the location values of the pair of pallets?

Comment: you are right, it is not clear. If the reader is placed in (0,0) the pallets are placed at (0,0), (-1,0), (1, 0), (0,-1), (0,1), (1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1). Are variables of pallets breed `dx-to-center-of-reader`,  `dy-to-center-of-reader`. Each server has the same number of pallets, some has tags other might be empty.

Comment: I could swap pallets locations but they might have the same dx- and dy-. The server has a variable named `pallets-being-served`that has all pallets. To change location I will need to update that variable (agentset) of the two involved servers and swap their dx- and dy- coordinates. And after that, update the variable `my-tags` of the two servers. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: the two pallets I want to move can be assigned to the same reader. I am trying to make a reorganization of pallets in a warehouse.

Comment: I think this question is not a general problem useful for more people than me. It does not worth to dedicate more of your time on this. Sorry and thank you very much for your help.